# Implement U2 and U3 gate in Q#

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, q#

I know that U1 equivalent gate of Qiskit in Q# is R1, but I would like to implement U2 and U3 gate of Qiskit in Q#, what is the best way ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to implement U2 directly or do you have a specific unitary in mind? What I mean by that is that U2/U3 are more general forms for unitaries, but algorithms typically only require a restricted gate that doesn't need to be expressed as U2/U3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gates [Rx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.rx), [Ry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.ry) and [Rz](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.rz) in Q# have the same definition as RXGate, RYGate and RZGate in Qiskit, and the [U2Gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.U2Gate.html) and [U3Gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.U3Gate.html) documentation offers decomposition of these gates into Rx, Ry and Rz, so I would just use that decomposition:

```
operation U2(psi : Double, lambda : Double, q : Qubit) : Unit is Adj + Ctl {
    Rz(lambda, q);
    Ry(0.5 * PI(), q);
    Rz(psi, q);
}
```

and a similar one for U3.

Comment: Thank you Mariaa, this is what I have tested but I have seen something :

If I simulate U2 or Rz/Ry/Rz gate with both Pi/4 for lambda and psi in Qiskit, then my state vectors are [ 0.707+0j, 0.5+0.5j ]

Then if I simulate Rz/Ry/Rz with Q#, then I dumpmachine to get state vectors, I got :
∣0❭:  0,500000 + -0,500000 i  ==  **********           [ 0,500000 ]      \  [ -0,78540 rad ]
∣1❭:  0,707107 +  0,000000 i  ==  ***********          [ 0,500000 ]     --- [  0,00000 rad ]

So there is a minus sign wich is different from Qiskit, is it normal ?

Comment: These states are the same up to a global phase (1-i)/√2 - multiply Qiskit state by this number and you'll get the expression Q# gives you. So yes, this is normal

Comment: Thank you Mariia, answer clear and complete as usual !